# local user cannot login while RADIUS is configured on Cisco Switch 3745

Tags: radius

I've configured RADIUS on my switch as below:

```
aaa new-model

!

aaa authentication login default group radius local

aaa authorization exec default group radius local 

!

radius-server host 172.16.1.20 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813

radius-server key sokootsk

!

line vty 0 30

login authentication default

!

username mbazgir secret 5 $1$cKA6$x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x.x
```

when attempt to **login to the switch** from **users on my server** through **telnet**, it successfully be done, but when I use the **local user** (mbazgir) to login to switch through **its console** while the **RADIUS server** **is not accessible**, the logging fails and the switch replays "Authentication fails".

why it fails?? How to solve it??